# Overriding standard "Submit" button to lock(uneditable) a record

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am looking for the correct syntax for a scenario where by once user clicks submit , the record would become locked i.e would not longer be editable. So, I have created a new custom button named "Submit to Lock" which needs to be overridden. I have created two record type where 1 record type's page layout have edit functionality and the other does not have the option to edit. Now, I am not too sure, how to call a action method/class from a overridden button;s java script function without writing a new VF page. Pls correct me if I am wrong with the syntax or approach. Thankx

---

```
 <script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  var account = sforce.sObject("Account");
  var id = sforce.apex.execute("myClass","makeContact:);
```

Comment: btw. what do you mean by standard "submit" button ?

Comment: by standard "submit" button - I mean to say I am not creating it in VF.I am creating it using Custom button and links option.

Comment: AND the method i want  to call is a simple method with signature like public static NonEditable(Object){}...It does not have "webService" attached with its name. In that case kindly suggest what should be the syntax for Java script.

Comment: it has to be declared as web service because Ajax makes a web service call.

Answer (score 1):

for Ajax buttons you need to include the libraries as follows

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
```

and then the code would be similar to this

```
sforce.apex.execute("myClass","myMethod", {myAccountId:'{!Account.Id}'});
```

assuming you have a method like the following

```
webService static void myMethod(Id myAccoundId) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're use case is, but for locking records using approval processes is a great approach.  You can just set the approval process to always approve and it will leave the record locked.

Using a record type change to a page layout with none of the fields editable is a good approach, but can have issues with fields that aren't allowed to be edited.  Users can also bypass them by editing records via list views.  There are tricks to cover all the holes, but it takes some effort to make sure you get them all.  Also, if the record type is visible anywhere on the page users can just changed the record type to unlock it.

I've also seen this done with a checkbox field.  You can then put in place a validation rule that fails for any record whose priorvalue(locked__c) is true.  Just remember to add some outs for system administrators.

Comment: Hi Ralph, the thing is, in my case, user will complete the assessment first, once they are done with the assessment the will submit it. Once it is submitted, the will be locked for that user level, however if his/her manger logs in, that same assessment should be in editable mode to any manager who is at a level higher than the user. In this case, can you suggest me some more detailed steps.

Comment: Sounds like a text book case for approval process.  If the manager is the approver you can set up the approval process to allow the approver to edit even while the record is locked for the submitter.  Read up on approval processes in [salesforce help](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=what_are_approvals.htm&language=en_US) and watch the intro to [workflows and approvals youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hilJXtRJcEU)

Comment: Ralph, Thanks for the links..Just wanted to reconfirm that in my case, i am not sure what should be used as a approval criteria as in this case user is hitting the submit button only AND I donot need any one's approval of that record, my main aim is to make the record locked once user hits submit button, where as that same record would remain as editable to manager. So, in manager display page or org there should not be any pending items- showing your approval required. hope I am able to make it clearer to you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it that way.  Only the approver (and sys admins) can edit (if set up that way), so if it auto-approves, there won't be any approvers.

Comment: Best advice would be to play around with approval processes a bit, if it doesn't fit you've got a lot of alternatives to try out.